# Play protected WMV files on a Mac?

Tags: drm, video

I'm trying to watch a protected WMV file on my Mac, but it seems that neither VLC nor Flip4Mac support DRMs. Well at least all I get is psychedelic images, such as this one:

[image: freaky]

Is there any way to play such videos on Mac OS X *without* resorting to any virtualization software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know the DRM aspects are built directly into Windows so won't work on OS X. Best bet would be virtualization I'm afraid!

Comment: That's my understanding also. I don't believe there has ever been a native Mac solution for playing DRM'ed WMV files.